# What is an Oracle ASSEMBLY?

Tags: oracle, plsql

What is an Oracle `ASSEMBLY`, in the context of Oracle SQL?

It's listed in `GV$SQLCOMMAND`.  Although `GV$SQLCOMMAND` is not a perfect guide to "real" SQL statements - for example it has `UPSERT` instead of `MERGE`.

```
   INST_ID COMMAND_TYPE COMMAND_NAME             CON_ID
---------- ------------ -------------------- ----------
         1          215 DROP ASSEMBLY                 0
         1          216 CREATE ASSEMBLY               0
         1          217 ALTER ASSEMBLY                0
```

The commands work although I'm not sure what they are doing.  Oddly the syntax requires a `/`, implying these objects may contain PL/SQL.

```
SQL> create or replace assembly some_assembly is 'some string';
  2  /

Assembly created.

SQL> select * from all_assemblies;

OWNER           ASSEMBLY_NAME   FILE_SPEC       SECURITY_L IDENTITY        STATUS
--------------- --------------- --------------- ---------- --------------- -------
JHELLER         SOME_ASSEMBLY   some string     SAFE                       VALID
```

The data dictionary views work and are documented: [ALL_ASSEMBLIES](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/refrn20564.htm#REFRN20564).

There are some Oracle products that use assemblies but I don't know if they tie directly to this SQL statement.  For example, there is the [Oracle® Fusion Middleware Using Oracle Virtual Assembly Builder](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/ovab/OVABU/intro.htm#OVABU0006), [Database assemblies in Oracle Enterprise Manager](https://blogs.oracle.com/oem/entry/new_database_assemblies_via_oracle), and [Database Extensions for .NET](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CLRNT/toc.htm) (which involve assemblies).

What is an `ASSEMBLY`?  A deprecated command?  An unimplemented or undocumented feature?  Or a real command that's documented somewhere I haven't looked?

Comment: Seems to have been new in Oracle 11g. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/whatsnew.htm#CJAIIJAG

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely nothing about this on the Internet - even the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1015.htm#REFRN20564) regarding the `%_ASSEMBLIES` views don't actually state what they show.

However, if you go digging around in `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin` you'll see the following reference to the data dictionary views (which sit on `assembly$`:

```
remark
remark  FAMILY "ASSEMBLIES"
remark
remark  Views for showing information about PL/SQL Assemblies:
remark  USER_ASSEMBLIES, ALL_ASSEMBLIES and DBA_ASSEMBLIES
remark
create or replace view USER_ASSEMBLIES
(ASSEMBLY_NAME, FILE_SPEC, SECURITY_LEVEL, IDENTITY, STATUS)
.......
```

This definitely says to me that these views, and the associated `CREATE/DROP/ALTER ASSEMBLY` commands, are for .NET stored procedure support.

Comment: I agree with you, yet I don't see the word .NET anywhere in the docs for this. Can someone with access to a Windows machine please deploy a demo .NET class into Oracle and verify that the views *_ASSEMBLIES then return a record?

Answer (score 2):

I think [this page](http://www-css.fnal.gov/dsg/external/oracle_dcm/v11.2.0.2/win.112/e12249/glossary.htm#i432693) has what you are looking for -

> Assembly: Assembly is Microsoft's term for the module that is created
>   when a DLL or .EXE is complied by a .NET compiler.

If I understand it correctly it is the .NET equivalent for Java's "class files".

Starting 11g, you can develop and deploy .NET procedures and functions in Oracle database.

Here is a link describing the steps to do that -

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20213_01/doc/win.112/e17724/devdeploy.htm

I didn't know this was called assemblies until now. So thanks for asking this question. :)

Comment: Can someone verify that after doing such a deployment, the views *_ASSEMBLIES return records? Until such time, both this answer and @tblPhil's above are still "just" extremely likely assumptions.

Comment: @Colin'tHart, after deploying a demo Oracle simply creates a library and a function (i.e. very similar approach to C external procedures). The difference is that the function uses dbms_clr under the hood and dbms_clr.executevarcharfunction in particular to call the function from DLL.

Comment: No new rows appear in dba_assemblies. After deploying .Net assembly the new objects in DB are the FUNCTION and the LIBRARY. I presume initially Oracle planed to implement something similar to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/database-objects/getting-started-with-clr-integration?view=sql-server-ver15 but eventually it simply creates a library object.